unsure about logic in elementary set theory exercise Tao Analysis I 3.5.9
This question is about the validity of a proof argument. I am asking because I am new to proofs.
This question is not specifically about solving the exercise.

The exercise is Tao Analysis I 4thed ex 3.5.9

Suppose that $I$ and $J$ are two sets, and for all $\alpha \in I$ let $A_{\alpha}$ be a set, and for all $\beta \in J$ let $B_{\beta}$ be a set. Show that
$$(\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}) \cap (\bigcup_{\beta \in J} B_{\beta}) = \bigcup_{(\alpha,\beta) \in I \times J} (A_{\alpha} \cap B_{\beta})$$
What happens if one interchanges all the union and intersection symbols here?


Note: I wanted to show this using a series of $\iff$ statements and not the more verbose proving both inclusions $\implies$ and $\impliedby$.
Let's start with the LHS.
$$x \in (\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}) \cap (\bigcup_{\beta \in J} B_{\beta}) \iff x \in (\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}) \land x \in (\bigcup_{\beta \in J} B_{\beta})$$
Using the definition of the union of sets, this means both of the following are true:

$x$ is an element of at least one $A_{\alpha}$, let's call one of them $A_{\alpha'}$
$x$ is an element of at least one $B_{\beta}$, let's call one of them $B_{\beta'}$

This gives us
$$\begin{align}x \in (\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}) \cap (\bigcup_{\beta \in J} B_{\beta}) &\iff x \in A_{\alpha'} \land x \in B_{\beta'} \\ \\ & \iff x \in A_{\alpha'} \cap B_{\beta'} \\ \\ & \iff x \in \bigcup_{(\alpha,\beta) \in I \times J} (A_{\alpha} \cap B_{\beta})\end{align}$$
Thus, we have shown
$$(\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}) \cap (\bigcup_{\beta \in J} B_{\beta}) = \bigcup_{(\alpha,\beta) \in I \times J} (A_{\alpha} \cap B_{\beta}) \; \square$$

My Doubt 1
My doubts are in using the specific $A_{\alpha'}$ and $B_{\beta'}$ which we know exist.
For example, consider the following:
$$x \in (\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}) \cap (\bigcup_{\beta \in J} B_{\beta}) \iff x \in A_{\alpha'} \land x \in B_{\beta'}$$
If the LHS is true we know there must exist an $A_{\alpha'}$ such that $x \in A_{\alpha'}$, and similarly there must exist a $B_{\beta'}$ such that $x \in B_{\beta'}$.
Now consider the RHS $x \in A_{\alpha'} \land x \in B_{\beta'}$. If this is true, then I would argue that the LHS is true because the argument "$x \in P \implies x \in P \cup Q$ for any set $Q$" is generalisable as "$x \in A_{\alpha'} \implies x \in \bigcup A_\alpha$". Am I right?

My Doubt 2
My next doubt arises from the following statement:
$$x \in A_{\alpha'} \cap B_{\beta'} \iff x \in \bigcup_{(\alpha,\beta) \in I \times J} (A_{\alpha} \cap B_{\beta})$$
The nature of my doubt is the same as Doubt 1.

If $\alpha'\in I$ and $\beta'\in J$ then indeed:
$$x \in (\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}) \cap (\bigcup_{\beta \in J} B_{\beta}) \impliedby x \in A_{\alpha'} \land x \in B_{\beta'}$$
but not:
$$x \in (\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}) \cap (\bigcup_{\beta \in J} B_{\beta}) \implies x \in A_{\alpha'} \land x \in B_{\beta'}$$
If you insist on using $\iff$ then you must make use of (existential) quantors:
$$x \in (\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}) \cap (\bigcup_{\beta \in J} B_{\beta}) \iff\exists \alpha\in I [x \in A_{\alpha}] \land\exists \beta\in J [x \in B_{\beta}]$$
The RHS can be worked out like this:$$\dots\iff\exists (\alpha,\beta)\in I\times J[x\in A_{\alpha}\cap B_{\beta}]\iff x\in\bigcup_{(\alpha,\beta)\in I\times J}(A_{\alpha}\cap B_{\beta})$$

Thank you @drhab - this is a very helpful answer for me as a beginner. It has identified clearly the error in my logic, and also shown me a direction for developing the solution using only $\iff$.

Glad to help, Penelope.

one more query if you have the patience. For the disjunctive scenario, can we say $(\exists \alpha\in I) ; [x \in A_{\alpha}] \lor (\exists \beta\in J) ; [x \in B_{\beta}] \iff (\exists (\alpha, \beta) \in I\times J ) ; [x\in A_{\alpha} \lor x \in B_{\beta}] $? I'm concerned that a $\beta \in J$ may not exists such that $x \in B_\beta$.

The "$\iff$-statement" in your comment is a true statement.
